# Recurring emailing of updated google sheets

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a script that emails the google sheets on a monthly basis. And that works fine.

Recurring option runs a script and then emails the spreadsheet.
The problem I've got is that it emails last opened spreadsheet rather than the updated version of it. And I'm not sure how to update the sheet and only then send it.

How can I make sure that the spreadsheet gets updated just before the email is sent?

I'm opening spreadsheet with ".openById" and it does get updated, but only after email is sent.

Sending email function is added at the end of the script that changes the spreadsheet.

Please help,

Comment: You should add code reference so others can help.

Comment: there's not much code needed - get spreadsheet, openbyid, update, sendAsAttachment. the problem isn't really in the code per se, it's the updating of the spreadsheet and timing. Maybe there's a formula that updates the spreadsheet?

Comment: How should sheet be updated? Like status of email you are sending?

Comment: You may want to look at the [.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()) method from the class SpreadsheetApp.

Comment: thank you @JPV! that was exactly what I needed, simple command that i couldn't find anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: Most welcome, @TomaszJ. I added my comment as answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out the [.flush() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()) : it applies all pending Spreadsheet changes.